# php - count number of times a word appears in a webpage pulled using fopen and fpassthru

Tags: php

Another question:
Here's my code atm:

```
$fp = fopen("https://********", 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);

$tmp = count_values($fp);
$cnt = $tmp[typelabel];
echo $cnt;
```

I want this code to count the number of times the word 'typelabel' appears in the variable $fp. I believe the count function only works on arrays, so any ideas? Also, would this work if I didnt print out the page contents (if i removed fpassthru?)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

`$typelabel_count = substr_count($data, 'typelabel');`

Sidenote:
A better way to read the data of an url is to just use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents).